# Can't delete space after a word in MS Word 2016

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

I have a Word document in which I cannot delete space after a certain word.

The picture below shows the space I can't delete:

[image]

When I try to delete it by placing the cursor after the word "are" on the first line, and press delete, the first "i" in the word "intitled" on the second line is deleted.

The pictures below show what I mean:

[image]
[image]

I would expect that if I have the cursor just after "are" on the first line, and press [delete], then the second line "be drawn back" to the the first line. (omg this is difficult to explain).

I do not know what to do. Please help!

Here is an example document to download:
https://github.com/rasmusrhl/hello-2/raw/master/example%20docx.docx

PS: This problem with the spaces arised after pasting from Evernote into Word.
PS: Really regret writing "entitled" as "intitled" but it's too late to change now :)

Comment: I don't really understand your issue. In your last screenshot there is no space after the word "are".

Comment: Are there nonbreaking spaces between the words from 'intitled' through 'programs'? (To search, in the Navigation pane, type ^s in the search box.) If those spaces are nonbreaking, replace with regular spaces.

Comment: Looks like you might have a right indent, set. Check your indent settings when you click on that line. Indent, or right margin settings... even check your paragraph settings.

Comment: The example document to download (hosted in a somewhat nasty service) does not match the description and screenshots. It has the first line ending with “immigrants” and the second line starting with “ireintitled to use”.

Comment: It is difficult to see what you mean by the problem description, but the example document contains something that surely causes some problems: almost all words after “immigrants” have NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE (U+202F) characters between them, instead of normal spaces.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela, thanks you are right, the file linked does not match the pictures, but the problem remains: I can't delete the whitespace on the first line. When I put the cursor after the last word on the first line and press delete, the first letter on the *second* line is deleted.

Comment: Jukka has the answer. The second line has a different type of spaces that don't allow it to be split. You need to correct all the second line changing the "weird" spaces to normal ones and you'll be good

Comment: Thanks @JukkaK.Korpela! Deleting the non breaking space solved the problem. How did you discover the non breaking space? If you post it as solution I will mark as answered.

Comment: If you encountered any weird situation and couldn't find the solution, just select the problematic text, right click on it, and from **"Styles"** menu choose **"Clear Formatting"**.

Comment: @AmirHossein: This problem has nothing to do with formatting, and clearing formatting will not fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all,
you can tell that the spaces on the second line
are different from the spaces on the first line
simply by looking closely at them:

[image: text with squares and triangles]

Note that some of the spaces (enclosed in red squares)
are shown as a centered dot, “·” (or “‧” or “⋅”),
when you have “Show/Hide ¶” turned on. 
These are ordinary spaces. 
Others (enclosed in blue triangles) are just blank. 
Spaces that appear as blank when you have “Show/Hide ¶” turned on
are not ordinary spaces; in your case, they are Narrow Non-Breaking Spaces. 
(Other special spaces display as a small circle,
like “°” or “<sup><sub>⊙</sub></sup>”.)

And the fact that the spaces are non-breaking
means that Microsoft Word treats “intitled to use the free national health care system, including preventive measures such as national cancer screening programs” all as one long word. 
Therefore, it doesn’t want to break it across lines;
since the ‘word’ doesn’t fit on the first line,
Word advances to the next line,
in the hopes that the ‘word’ will fit on that line. 
(Note that your browser treats it the same way.) 
When you delete the space between “are” and “intitled”,
you attach “are” to the beginning of the ‘word’,
so it becomes “areintitled to use the free national health care system,…”,
and so the “are” is moved to the second line. 
And so you can fix your problem
by replacing the non-breaking spaces with ordinary spaces.

If you are suspicious of a character,
select it and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>. 
The character will (usually) be replaced
by its four- or five-digit Unicode value. 
An ordinary space is 0020. 
As stated in the comments, a narrow non-breaking space is 202F. 
If, after you’ve identified a character,
you decide that you want to keep it,
just press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> again
(with the Unicode value still selected) and it will switch back.

By the way, your description of the problem doesn’t match your images:

- You say that you cannot delete the space (between “are” and “intitled”),
  and that, when you try, you actually delete the “i”. 
  But the “after” image shows that the space between “are” and “intitled”
  is deleted and the “i” is still there:
      [image: “areintitled” with the insertion point (cursor) between “are” and “intitled”]
- You say “the space is still there”,
  but the space that is still there
  is the space between “immigrants” and “are”
  (which you didn’t try to delete).